# Webpack 4, React project, Bundle sizes

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Using Webpack 4 in a React project so there are good few NPM packages in use but the bundle sizes are massive - e.g 6MB.

I've read over the Webpack 4 docs to see how I can minify and build production ready bundles but the file sizes don't seem to reduce that much.

I've also tried splitting up the bundles but with no real success. E.g Tried to put all React related packages into 1 bundle but then this breaks the web app - browser throws errors saying it can't find packages. I've probably done something wrong though!

So I'm looking for some help on improving my build setup and splitting the files into smaller files and generally just making things a bit better.

My Webpack 4 config file:

```
const path = require('path');
const precss = require('precss');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const packageJson = require('./package.json');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

const filenames = {
    css: '[name].bundle.css',
    js: '[name].bundle.js',
};

console.log('#########################################');

/* Cache busted names for production */
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    console.log('#   XXXXXX v', packageJson.version, ' PRODUCTION   #');

    const timestamp = +new Date();

    filenames.css = `[name].bundle.${timestamp}.css`;
    filenames.js = `[name].bundle.${timestamp}.js`;
} else {
    console.log('#   XXXXXX v', packageJson.version, ' DEVELOPMENT   #');
}

console.log('#########################################');
console.log('');

module.exports = (env, options) => ({
    entry: './src/assets/js/Scheduler.jsx',
    output: {
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: `assets/js/${filenames.js}`,
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
    },
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: /node_modules/,
    },
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
    },
    devtool: (options.mode === 'production') ? 'source-map' : 'cheap-module-source-map',
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        watchContentBase: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/,
            use: [
                'babel-loader',
                'eslint-loader',
            ],
        }, {
            test: /\.(css)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {
                    /* Interprets `@import` and `url()` like `import/require()` and will resolve them */
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                    },
                },
            ],
        }, {
            test: /\.(scss)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'css-hot-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                    },
                },
                /**
                 * Commented out as we want to extract the styles into a seperate file which the mini CSS extract plugin will do.
                 * If you want to keep the styles within the scripts, comment this back in and comment out mini CSS extract plugin line below.
                 */
                /*
                {
                    loader: 'style-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                    },
                },
                */
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {
                    /* Interprets `@import` and `url()` like `import/require()` and will resolve them */
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                    },
                }, {
                    /* Loader for webpack to process CSS with PostCSS */
                    loader: 'postcss-loader',
                    options: {
                        autoprefixer: {
                            browsers: ['last 3 versions'],
                        },
                        plugins: loader => [
                            precss(),
                            autoprefixer(),
                        ],
                        sourceMap: true,
                    },
                }, {
                    /* Loads a SASS/SCSS file and compiles it to CSS */
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                    },
                },
            ],
        }, {
            test: /\.woff2?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/,
            use: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
        }, {
            test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?[\s\S]+)?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/,
            use: 'file-loader',
        }, {
            test: /\.(png|jp(e*)g|svg|gif)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/,
            use: [{
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                    limit: 8000, /* Convert images < 8kb to base64 strings */
                    name: 'assets/img/[name]-[hash].[ext]',
                },
            }],
        }, {
            test: /\.html$/,
            exclude: /node_modules|bower_components/,
            use: {
                loader: 'html-loader',
                options: {
                    minimize: true,
                },
            },
        }, {
            test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//,
            use: 'imports-loader?jQuery=jquery',
        }],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.jsx', '.js', '.scss', '.css', '.html'],
    },
    performance: {
        hints: false,
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'initial',
                    test: /node_modules/,
                },
            },
        },
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                cache: true,
                parallel: true,
                sourceMap: true,
            }),
            new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin(),
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: `assets/css/${filenames.css}`,
        }),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            hash: (options.mode === 'production'),
        }),
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: 'src/404.html',
            filename: '404.html',
            hash: (options.mode === 'production'),
        }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        }),
        new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([
            {
                force: true,
                cache: true,
                to: 'assets/icons',
                from: 'src/assets/icons',
            }, {
                force: true,
                cache: true,
                to: 'assets/img',
                from: 'src/assets/img',
            }, {
                force: true,
                cache: true,
                to: 'assets/fonts',
                from: 'src/assets/fonts',
            }, {
                force: true,
                cache: true,
                to: 'assets/fonts',
                from: 'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts',
            },
        ]),
    ],
});
```

My package.json file:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.4.7",
    "autoprefixer": "^8.6.5",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.15.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "babel-jest": "^22.4.4",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-airbnb": "^2.5.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "css-hot-loader": "^1.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.13.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "jest": "^22.4.4",
    "jest-cli": "^22.4.4",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.1",
    "moxios": "^0.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.3",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.6",
    "precss": "^3.1.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.1",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "sinon": "^5.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.7",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.16.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
},
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "classlist-polyfill": "^1.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "element-closest": "^2.0.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "fastclick": "^1.0.6",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "font-awesome-filetypes": "^1.2.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "loaders.css": "^0.1.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "mailcheck": "^1.1.1",
    "mobile-drag-drop": "^2.3.0-rc.1",
    "mock-local-storage": "^1.0.5",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "moment-range": "^4.0.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "query-string": "^6.1.0",
    "raf": "^3.4.0",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-avatar": "^3.1.2",
    "react-block-ui": "^1.1.1",
    "react-confirm": "^0.1.17",
    "react-datepicker": "^1.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-form-with-constraints": "^0.9.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.4",
    "react-image": "^1.3.1",
    "react-loaders": "^3.0.1",
    "react-number-format": "^3.5.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-toastify": "^4.1.0",
    "reactstrap": "^5.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sortablejs": "^1.7.0",
    "vanilla-autofill-event": "^1.0.3",
    "zxcvbn": "^4.4.2"
}
```

Comment: First of all check if you really need each of those packages

Comment: Yeah, I have only installed the libraries I require. I have also installed source-map-explorer to see which packages are added weight.

Comment: 1. Are you sure that build was a production build? 2. Try gzip the bundle, it should help a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Size of development bundle is not a big deal since you work on your local machine. The important thing is production bundle should be minimized. Because when your app goes live, it uses the production bundle. So smaller bundle means, the server that provided by your hosting platform, will be sending the production assets faster.

In production mode, packages that you installed will automatically strip out a lot of the things that your library includes for the development process.

```
**Minification**
```

Minification does things like removing whitespace, removing comments, removing non-required semicolons, reducing hex code lengths...

The file remains perfectly valid code. You wouldn't want to try to read it or work with it, but it's not breaking any rules. The browser can read it and use it just like it could the original file.

Minification simply alters the text while file compression completely rewrites the binary code within a file.

```
  const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
  optimization:{
  minimize:true //this should be set
  minimizer:[new TerserPluign()]}
```

**Compressing Assets in Production**

[compression-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression-webpack-plugin) uses gzip algorithm by default. Gzip is standard and understood by all the browsers. IN the webpack.prod-client.js

```
    `const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");

     plugins: [
          new CompressionPlugin(),
        ]`
```

This will compress your assets files except "jpeg" images. Because jpeg is already a compressed file type.

We created gzip files but we cannot load them yet. Because in network tab, content type of the files should be gzip. We need a better server configuration.

```
   npm i express-static-gzip

   const expressStaticGzip = require("express-static-gzip");
   server.use(expressStaticGzip("dist")); //make sure you use this middleware first
```

We download files as gzip but the browser uses the uncompressed version.

Brotli is another compression algorithm originally developed by Google, and offers compression superior to gzip.

```
  const BrotliPlugin = require("brotli-webpack-plugin");
  new BrotliPlugin(),
  server.use(expressStaticGzip("dist", { enableBrotli: true, orderPreference: ["br", "gzip"] }));
```

Now we have a new set of files: original files, gz version and br versions which are even smaller.

Webpack compression will compress your files one-time - during your build run. Those compressed versions are then saved to disk. express-static-gzip can then serve those pre-compiled versions, so you're not taking the performance hit of gzipping at the point of request. This is useful if Node.js is directly responding to your HTTP requests and you're not using an upstream proxy/load balancer.